# Word VBA not filtering matches for Dir string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using Word 2019 trying to write a VBA sub that opens all the .docx files in the current directory with names that begins with a number and contain the text "Values". E.g., so it would open "1 Values.docx".

I'm trying to used `Dir` but when I step through the code it's not finding any matches even though there are some in the current directory. Below is a snippet of code. Why isn't `Dir` returning matches for "1 Values.docx" and "2 Values.docx"?

```
Sub FindTables()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FoundTables As Boolean
    
    ' Set the folder path to the current directory
    FolderPath = ThisDocument.path
    
    ' Loop through all the files in the folder
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "\[0-9]*Values*.docx")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        FoundTables = True
        
        ' Move to the next file
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    ' Save the new document with the concatenated tables
    If FoundTables Then
        MsgBox "Found tables.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No matching tables found.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dir does not accept this way (in fact any way) of searching for numbers. I am afraid that you need to search for `"*Values.docx"` and then, in the iteration check as If Filename like "#*" then do whatever you need with file names starting with a digit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dir` doesn't support [0-9] as pattern matching. Please try.

```vb
    ' Loop through all the files in the folder
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*Values*.docx")
    Do While FileName <> ""
        If VBA.IsNumeric(Left(FileName, 1)) Then 'FileName starts with a digit
            Debug.Print FileName
            FoundTables = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        ' Move to the next file
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
```